# jQuery ui Grid examples for the beginner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a small application I am working on. I have reference tables and would really like to be able to use the jQuery UI grid plug-in for these when it's ready. I looked at other products. They are some good products out there that are years ahead of the jQuery UI grid. However I would like to go with **the official jQuery UI product** even if it means waiting a long time. Looking at the state of the roadmap I am guessing it will perhaps a year before we see this ready.

In the mean time I would love to have a chance to experiment.

Does anyone have any example of how they have used the **jQuery UI grid**. I know there are all kinds of examples out there on the jQuery UI site but these are not aimed at a beginner. Right now I am not even sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real documentation yet on the subject as it is still in development.

Nevertheless, you can already find some examples and how-to use informations:

- [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/grid): the "grid" branch contains the source of the wudget and two sub directories with examples
- this [page](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37927153/Grid-SPF) shows examples for sorting, paging and filtering features
- this [page](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/40076465/Grid-Editing) talsk about grid editing

I think the best way to learn more is to go on a build yourself an example and try make it work, debug to detect what you're doing wrong, etc...